# How to make a div minimum width based on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with table inside. The div is full in width, but whenever I resized the screen, the div will reduce its size then its content will overlapped the div.

Now, I want the minimum width of the div based on the contents(table).
My main div is **class="search".**
Here is the link for my codes:

```css
.search {
  border: 2px solid #FDBF3B;
  background-color: #FFEBC1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.search table {
  border: none;
}

.search .header {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDBF3B;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: #000F1F;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.search .buttons {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FDBF3B;
  padding-top: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  padding: 7px;
  min-height: 480px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<DIV class=inner>
  <DIV class=search sizset="false" sizcache017720493147691946="40 33 1">
    <DIV class=header>Search Options </DIV>
    <TABLE sizset="false" sizcache017720493147691946="40 33 1">
      <TBODY sizset="false" sizcache017720493147691946="40 33 1">
        <TR>
          <TD></TD>
          <TD class=LABEL>
            <SPAN id=LBL_NAME>Name:</SPAN>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT name=NAME style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff" type=text size=15 maxLength=10 data-dpmaxz-eid="4">
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD></TD>
          <TD class=LABEL>
            <SPAN id=LBL_ADDRESS>Address:</SPAN>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT name=ADDRESS style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff" type=text size=40 maxLength=50 data-dpmaxz-eid="5"> </TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <DIV class=buttons>
      <INPUT name=SEARCH class=BUTTON type=button value=Search>
      <INPUT name=SEARCH class=BUTTON type=button value=Clear>
      <INPUT name=CREATE class=BUTTON type=button value=Create> </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: @Teemu its about the link jsfiddle...

Comment: @Teemu I have updated my question

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dg87nmjy/)?

Comment: @Teemu yes, like that one,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dg87nmjy/1/

Comment: I will now try it in the system im using... thank you

Comment: @Teemu I have noticed that you've added codes in class="inner" but the main div is class="search"

Comment: How would I know, you didn't tell ... `.inner` is the outmost element in your HTML, that's where the things should happen. If you're using that same class somewhere else, and the new style is not appropriate, create a new class for this case. Or just add the additional CSS to `.search` rules ...

Comment: @Teemu, I have updated my question, sorry... I transferred your codes, it worked also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

apply min-width to parent div and manage overflow in body. Whenever you reduce widnow width lesser then search div's width, there will be a scroll in body.

```
    .body{
       overflow: scroll;
    }
    .search {
       min-width:380px;
    }
```